# HttpWebRequest slow fix by setting Proxy to null

Tags: proxy, httpwebrequest

I rectified my HttpWebRequest initial calls being slow by using the suggestion mentioned at

[Why is this WebRequest code slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754333/why-is-this-webrequest-code-slow)

One of the suggestions mentioned to set the Proxy to null and things will speed up.

I have done this and it worked.

However Im concerned about the impact of this when I deploy this at some client sites....

It may be at some client sites that have configured their domain to go through a proxy to reach the server in which I am making my HttpWebRequest to.

Will setting Proxy properly to null impinge upon this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wondered the same thing too.  I was not able to find any answer to this question, though.

However, I did find that you can accomplish the same effect as hard coding httprequest.Proxy = null by adding a setting to the application config file:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy bypassonlocal="true" usesystemdefault="false" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

My thinking is that if I ever find myself at a customer site where I need to change the automatic proxy detection I can remove the settings from the config file.

I found this fix at the following site:
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2005/Dec/14/Slow-Http-client-calls-from-ASPNET-20-Make-sure-you-check-your-Proxy-Settings