# Unity 3D Puts/Deletes http methods

Tags: c#, php, rest, http, unity-game-engine

I'm thinking of porting a JavaScript web app to C# Unity3D (Free / Personal Version) for an RPG I'm developing. I have an extensible, separate API built in PHP Laravel 5.1, which my game interacts with through jQuery http calls.

I need to continue making standard restful calls, `get`, `post`, `put`, `delete`, etc within Unity but have only found `UnityEngine.WWW#` which makes `gets` and `posts`.

[This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224602/a-method-for-making-http-requests-on-unity-ios) shares the other available Unity3D http methods, but none which actually get all restful calls in one. I'm asking again because this was posted in **2012** and I haven't found any updates which satisfy this within the [updated documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

There is [Best HTTP Basic](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10765) and [Best HTTP](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10872) for $45 and $55, but was thinking there would be other free options.

Am I missing something within Unity that allows for standard restful calls?

Comment: Are you using Unity pro or free version?

Comment: @Programmer free / personal version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WebClient` and `WebRequest` are both available in Unity and looks like it will only work with Pro Unity version just like any other API from the `System.Net` namespace. I don't know if this restriction has changed in Unity 5. They support all those restful calls mentioned in your question.

Unity Added a new API called [UnityWebRequest](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) in version **5.2** with mobile platform support in **5.3**. It was designed to replace `WWW` and it supports **all** the restfull calls listed in your question. Below are example for each one. This is not a full example. You can find full examples in the link I provided above.

```
//Get
UnityWebRequest get = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://www.myserver.com/foo.txt");

//Post
UnityWebRequest post = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://www.myserver.com/foo.txt","Hello");

//Put
byte[] myData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is some test data");
UnityWebRequest put = UnityWebRequest.Put("http://www.my-server.com/upload", myData);

//Delete
UnityWebRequest delete = UnityWebRequest.Delete("http://www.myserver.com/foo.txt");
```

You can see complete example for each one including posting with json [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46008025/3785314).

Comment: Just a Unity 5 update - these are free features and seem to be fully supported in Unity 5.4+. 
I'm using them in Unity 5.3 (listed as experimental) and they're working.

Comment: @hubatish `UnityWebRequest` is free and  I did not say it needs pro. `WebClient` and `WebRequest`  are what need pro but not anymore in Unity 5. FYI, `UnityWebRequest` is no longer experimental in 5.4. You should be using 5.4 by now. It fixed many problems with it.