# Does HttpWebResponse needs yield/coroutine to wait for message from server?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest

Hi I am trying to implement a "PUT" request to send JSON string to my server, below is my code

```
public static string PUT (string url, string jsonStr){
    string msg = "";

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())){
        sw.Write(jsonStr);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }

    try{
        HttpWebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            msg = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }catch(WebException ex){
        msg = ex.Message;
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Right now I can receive msg from my server like "Success!" which is pretty short. But I wonder if this method should be written as a coroutine and do like "yield return response" or "yield return streamReader.EndofStream()" to ensure reading the response after all messages have been got from server.

I am using Unity3D which has its own web request method - "UnityWebRequest", it needs "yield return unityWebRequest.send()" to wait until request completed. That's why I think maybe HttpWebRequest also needs that.

Comment: You should not be using HttpWebRe* classes, you should be using the WWW class

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I have tried both UnityWebRequest and WWW, they don't work (still wondering why), that's why I use C#'s webRequest instead.

Comment: Your problem with WWW might  be that it only accepts GET and POST requests

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Yes, that's the reason I gave up WWW, but actually UnityWebRequest can do all kinds of requests including PUT, DELETE, etc. But sometimes it works, sometimes not. It is still in UnityEngine.Experimental.Networking so I guess it is still in beta, not a stable one.

Comment: No, its not. Download Unity 5.4 and you will see that it has been moved out of UnityEngine.Experimental.Networking.

Comment: @Programmer OMG Unity did remove it. Another reason not using it.

Comment: **"Another reason not using it**"  Umm...They moved it to the permanent namespace which is `UnityEngine.Networking`. You can use it and if possible use it.

Comment: @Programmer lol got it, thanks your answer!

Comment: You are welcome. If your question is answered, you can ahead and accept it as answer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png You can do that to your other questions that are answered too. Happy coding!

Comment: The use of WWW and UnityWebRequest, from what I can tell, is very inefficient if you make repeated calls and use SSL. The connection and hand shake over SSL takes up to 400ms and kills performance. From what I can tell neither classes uses or respects the `Connection: keep-alive` header. Something like this seems necessary as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does HttpWebResponse needs yield/coroutine to wait for message from
>   server?

**No.**

> But I wonder if this method should be written as a coroutine and do
>   like "yield return response" or "yield return
>   streamReader.EndofStream()" to ensure reading the response after all
>   messages have been got from server.

You can use coroutine/yiled with [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) and [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html). You can learn more about UnityWebRequest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37513580/3785314).

For `HttpWebResponse`, you have to use it in another `Thread` or use the asynchronous version of it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202896/3785314) is an example. If you don't do this, expect your game to be freezing most of the time, especially when you are receiving large data.

Comment: I am considering this one, it seems exactly what I want. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12606963/3577115)

Comment: @milanow Good. Use any that works for you. As long as this answers your question that you can't use `yield coroutine` with `HttpWebResponse`.