# Obtain data from UnityWebRequest while still downloading?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, yield

I have this code that makes a REST call:

```
public IEnumerator GetCooroutine(string route)
{
    string finalURL = URL + route;
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(finalURL);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("GET succesfull. Response: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

I need to access the data or body of the request while they are receiving, and use it for other stuff. I don't want to wait until it has finished receiving them before accessing them.

If I use `yield`, the code waits until the `send` finishes it's execution, and I don't want that.

Comment: What data do you need to access while they are receiving?

Comment: Images from a video, and i need to acces them

Comment: Sorry for not answering I was on holiday. But yes, it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do it with `UnityWebRequest` but you have to perform extra work. The secret is to use `DownloadHandlerScript` with `UnityWebRequest`.

Create a separate class and make it derive from `DownloadHandlerScript` instead of `MonoBehaviour`. In the example below, I will call it `CustomWebRequest`. Override the `bool ReceiveData(byte[] data, int dataLength)`, `void CompleteContent()` and the `void ReceiveContentLength(int contentLength)` functions inside it.

Here is an example of the `CustomWebRequest` class:

```
public class CustomWebRequest : DownloadHandlerScript
{
    // Standard scripted download handler - will allocate memory on each ReceiveData callback
    public CustomWebRequest()
        : base()
    {
    }

    // Pre-allocated scripted download handler
    // Will reuse the supplied byte array to deliver data.
    // Eliminates memory allocation.
    public CustomWebRequest(byte[] buffer)
        : base(buffer)
    {
    }

    // Required by DownloadHandler base class. Called when you address the 'bytes' property.
    protected override byte[] GetData() { return null; }

    // Called once per frame when data has been received from the network.
    protected override bool ReceiveData(byte[] byteFromServer, int dataLength)
    {
        if (byteFromServer == null || byteFromServer.Length < 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("CustomWebRequest :: ReceiveData - received a null/empty buffer");
            return false;
        }

        //Do something with or Process byteFromServer here


        return true;
    }

    // Called when all data has been received from the server and delivered via ReceiveData
    protected override void CompleteContent()
    {
        Debug.Log("CustomWebRequest :: CompleteContent - DOWNLOAD COMPLETE!");
    }

    // Called when a Content-Length header is received from the server.
    protected override void ReceiveContentLength(int contentLength)
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("CustomWebRequest :: ReceiveContentLength - length {0}", contentLength));
    }
}
```

And to use it to start the download, just create new instance of `UnityWebRequest` and use `CustomWebRequest` as the `downloadHandler` before calling the `SendWebRequest` function. No coroutine required for this and you don't even have to yield anything. This is how to do it:

```
UnityWebRequest webRequest;
//Pre-allocate memory so that this is not done each time data is received
byte[] bytes = new byte[2000];

void Start()
{
    string url = "http://yourUrl/mjpg/video.mjpg";
    webRequest = new UnityWebRequest(url);
    webRequest.downloadHandler = new CustomWebRequest(bytes);
    webRequest.SendWebRequest();
}
```

That's it.

- When Unity first makes the request, `ReceiveContentLength(int
  contentLength)` is called. You can use the `contentLength` parameter to determine the total number of bytes you will receive from that request.
- The `ReceiveData` function is called each time new data is received
  and from that function, you can access that current data from the
  `byteFromServer` parameter and the length of it from the `dataLength`
  parameter.
- When Unity is done receiving data, the `CompleteContent` function is
  called.