# Download large file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

By downloading a file with `UnityEngine.WWW`, I get the error

> OverflowException: Number overflow.

I found out the error is caused form the structure itself, because the byte-array has more bytes than int.MaxValue can allocate (~2GB).

The error is fired by returning the array with `www.bytes`, which means, that the framework probably stores the array in on other way.

How can I access the downloaded data in another way or is there an alternative for bigger files?

```
public IEnumerator downloadFile()
{
    WWW www = new WWW(filesource);

    while(!www.isDone)
    {
        progress = www.progress;
        yield return null;
    }

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        data = www.bytes; // <- Errormessage fired here
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of file is this and are you trying to save it after ? Note that it would be great to also mention your Unity version

Comment: Its a videofile (mp4), but the error is indipendend from the type, because it happens with all filetypes. I use version 2017.3.1f1
I save it with File.WriteAllBytes(path, data), but its not possible to access the Array itself from www

Comment: Ok but what you trying to do with it after downloading it? Play it? Save it? Answer depends on that

Comment: At first I store it and load it after that for video-playback. It works well up to 2GB.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**New answer (Unity 2017.2 and above)**

Use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity/46008025#46008025) with [`DownloadHandlerFile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerFile.html). The `DownloadHandlerFile` class is new and is used to download and save file directly while preventing high memory usage.

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    string url = "http://dl3.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm";

    string vidSavePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Videos");
    vidSavePath = Path.Combine(vidSavePath, "MyVideo.webm");

    //Create Directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(vidSavePath)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(vidSavePath));
    }

    var uwr = new UnityWebRequest(url);
    uwr.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET;
    var dh = new DownloadHandlerFile(vidSavePath);
    dh.removeFileOnAbort = true;
    uwr.downloadHandler = dh;
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
        Debug.Log(uwr.error);
    else
        Debug.Log("Download saved to: " + vidSavePath.Replace("/", "\\") + "\r\n" + uwr.error);
}
```

---

**OLD answer (Unity 2017.1 and below)** Use if you want to access each bytes while the file is downloading)

A problem like this is why Unity's [`UnityWebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity/46008025#46008025) was made but it won't work directly because `WWW` API is now implemented on top of the `UnityWebRequest` API in the newest version of Unity which means that if you get error with the `WWW` API, you will also likely get that same error with `UnityWebRequest`. Even if it works, you'll likely have have issues on mobile devices with the small ram like Android.

What to do is use UnityWebRequest's [`DownloadHandlerScript`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerScript.html) feature which allows you to download data in chunks. By downloading data in chunks, you can prevent causing the overflow error. The `WWW` API did not implement this feature so `UnityWebRequest` and `DownloadHandlerScript` must be used to download the data in chunks. You can read how this works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524324/obtain-data-from-unitywebrequest-while-still-downloading/49533859#49533859).

While this should solve your current issue, you may run into another memory issue when trying to save that large data with `File.WriteAllBytes`. Use `FileStream` to do the saving part and close it only when the download has finished.

Create a custom `UnityWebRequest` for downloading data in chunks as below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class CustomWebRequest : DownloadHandlerScript
{
    // Standard scripted download handler - will allocate memory on each ReceiveData callback
    public CustomWebRequest()
        : base()
    {
    }

    // Pre-allocated scripted download handler
    // Will reuse the supplied byte array to deliver data.
    // Eliminates memory allocation.
    public CustomWebRequest(byte[] buffer)
        : base(buffer)
    {

        Init();
    }

    // Required by DownloadHandler base class. Called when you address the 'bytes' property.
    protected override byte[] GetData() { return null; }

    // Called once per frame when data has been received from the network.
    protected override bool ReceiveData(byte[] byteFromServer, int dataLength)
    {
        if (byteFromServer == null || byteFromServer.Length < 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("CustomWebRequest :: ReceiveData - received a null/empty buffer");
            return false;
        }

        //Write the current data chunk to file
        AppendFile(byteFromServer, dataLength);

        return true;
    }

    //Where to save the video file
    string vidSavePath;
    //The FileStream to save the file
    FileStream fileStream = null;
    //Used to determine if there was an error while opening or saving the file
    bool success;

    void Init()
    {
        vidSavePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Videos");
        vidSavePath = Path.Combine(vidSavePath, "MyVideo.webm");


        //Create Directory if it does not exist
        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(vidSavePath)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(vidSavePath));
        }


        try
        {
            //Open the current file to write to
            fileStream = new FileStream(vidSavePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            Debug.Log("File Successfully opened at" + vidSavePath.Replace("/", "\\"));
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            success = false;
            Debug.LogError("Failed to Open File at Dir: " + vidSavePath.Replace("/", "\\") + "\r\n" + e.Message);
        }
    }

    void AppendFile(byte[] buffer, int length)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            try
            {
                //Write the current data to the file
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                Debug.Log("Written data chunk to: " + vidSavePath.Replace("/", "\\"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                success = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Called when all data has been received from the server and delivered via ReceiveData
    protected override void CompleteContent()
    {
        if (success)
            Debug.Log("Done! Saved File to: " + vidSavePath.Replace("/", "\\"));
        else
            Debug.LogError("Failed to Save File to: " + vidSavePath.Replace("/", "\\"));

        //Close filestream
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    // Called when a Content-Length header is received from the server.
    protected override void ReceiveContentLength(int contentLength)
    {
        //Debug.Log(string.Format("CustomWebRequest :: ReceiveContentLength - length {0}", contentLength));
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
UnityWebRequest webRequest;
//Pre-allocate memory so that this is not done each time data is received
byte[] bytes = new byte[2000];

IEnumerator Start()
{
    string url = "http://dl3.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm";
    webRequest = new UnityWebRequest(url);
    webRequest.downloadHandler = new CustomWebRequest(bytes);
    webRequest.SendWebRequest();
    yield return webRequest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes, but this solution works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve from the bytes the status code of the request?because if the file no exists, it stores the file with a couple of byte. I tried it in ReceiveData

Comment: You mean to check if the file exist on the server before saving it? That sounds complicated and I think you should create new question about it. I will try to come up with something.

Comment: I've found a solution. I added a bool if filestream has been created, moved the creation at the beginning of AppendFile. In receiveData I check if the datalength is 14 (length of the errorMessage of File not found), check in this case if System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteFromServer).Contains("File not found") and return in this case false with success false.

Comment: See my edit in my answer. `removeFileOnAbort` might be useful for this with the new `DownloadHandlerFile` API. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I tested now the new answer, it works good. Thank you!