# Get file/AssetBundle size from http request before downloading file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Question:

I want to get the size of assetBundle before finishing download the file. And I can show the remaining time to user. In Unity2018.2 , can we get the **file size** or **downloaded file size** that let me multiply by **progress**? Or there is other ways to calculate the **remaining time**?

I know **WWW.responseHeaders** contain the information, but it seems need to finish downloading.

Here is my code currently.

```
    using (WWW downloadPackageWWW = new WWW(pkg.url))
    {
        while (!downloadPackageWWW.isDone)
        {
            print("progress: " + downloadPackageWWW.progress * 100 + "%");    
            yield return null;
        }

        if (downloadPackageWWW.error != null)
            print("WWW download had an error:" + downloadPackageWWW.error);
        if (downloadPackageWWW.responseHeaders.Count > 0) 
            print(pkg.fileName + ": " + downloadPackageWWW.responseHeaders["Content-Length"]+" byte");

        byte[] bytes = downloadPackageWWW.bytes;
        File.WriteAllBytes(pkgPath, bytes);

    }
```

--

**Update:**

To get the remaining time, I come up a ideal that calculate by **Time.deltaTime**, and we don't need to know the total file size and download speed.

```
float lastProgress = 0;
while (!www.isDone)
{  
     float deltaProgress = www.progress - lastProgress;
     float progressPerSec = deltaProgress / Time.deltaTime;
     float remaingTime = (1 - www.progress) / progressPerSec;
     print("Remaining: " + remaingTime + " sec"); 
     lastProgress = www.progress;
     yield return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using Unity's `UnityWebRequest` API to make we requests. In your current Unity version the `WWW` API is now implemented on top of `UnityWebRequest` under the hood but it's still lacking many features.

You can get the size of your file without downloading or waiting for it to finish downloading in two ways:

**1**.Make a `HEAD` request with `UnityWebRequest.Head`. You can then use `UnityWebRequest.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length")` to get the size of the data.

```
IEnumerator GetFileSize(string url, Action<long> resut)
{
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Head(url);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
    string size = uwr.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length");

    if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Getting Length: " + uwr.error);
        if (resut != null)
            resut(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (resut != null)
            resut(Convert.ToInt64(size));
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
void Start()
{
    string url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip";
    StartCoroutine(GetFileSize(url,
    (size) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("File Size: " + size);
    }));
}
```

---

**2**. Another option is to use `UnityWebRequest` with `DownloadHandlerScript` then override the `void ReceiveContentLength(int contentLength)` function. Once you call the `SendWebRequest` function, The `ReceiveContentLength` function should give you the download size in the `contentLength` parameter. You should then abort the `UnityWebRequest` request. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689859/download-large-file/50690420#50690420) is one example on how to use `DownloadHandlerScript`.

I would go with the first solution since it's simpler, easier and requires less resources to work.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try these solutions.