# Sending http requests in C# with Unity

Tags: c#, http, unity-game-engine

How can I send HTTP GET and POST requests in C# with Unity?

What I want is:

- send json data in post request (I use Unity serializer, so no need in
  new one, I just want to pass a string in post data and have the ability to
  set ContentType to application/json);
- get response code and body without any problems;
- do it all asynchronously without blocking UI rendering.

What I've tried:

- implementing with HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse, but it's too hard and low level (if I won't find anything better, I'll have to use it);
- using Unity WWW, but it doesn't match my requirements;
- using some external packages from NuGet - Unity doesn't accept them :(

Most problems were with threading, I'm not experienced enough in it in C#.
IDE, I use, is Intellij Rider.

Comment: Use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: If you want to do this async, you should use **WWW** and **IEnumerator** that Unity provides, if it's not what you wanted, then write own **HttpClient** with threading, but it's complicated

Comment: HTTP Client can be done async in unity.

Comment: You can use NuGet packages with Unity, see this Open Source plugin to use promises instead of Coroutines https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The `WWW` API should get this done but `UnityWebRequest` replaced it so I will answer the newer API. It's really simple. You have to use coroutine to do this with Unity's API otherwise you have have to use one of C# standard web request API and Thread. With coroutine you can yield the request until it is done. This will not block the main Thread or prevent other scripts from running.

**Note**:

<sup>For the examples below, if you are using anything below *Unity 2017.2*, replace `SendWebRequest()` with `Send()` and then replace `isNetworkError` with `isError`. This will then work for the lower version of Unity. Also, if you need to access the downloaded data in a binary form instead, replace `uwr.downloadHandler.text` with `uwr.downloadHandler.data`. Finally, the `SetRequestHeader` function is used to set the header of the request.</sup>

**GET request**:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(getRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com"));
}

IEnumerator getRequest(string uri)
{
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

---

**POST request with Form**:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(postRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com"));
}

IEnumerator postRequest(string url)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("myField", "myData");
    form.AddField("Game Name", "Mario Kart");

    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

---

**POST request with Json**:

```
 void Start()
 {
     StartCoroutine(postRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com", "your json"));
 }

 IEnumerator postRequest(string url, string json)
 {
     var uwr = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
     byte[] jsonToSend = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json);
     uwr.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(jsonToSend);
     uwr.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
     uwr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

     //Send the request then wait here until it returns
     yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

     if (uwr.isNetworkError)
     {
         Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
     }
 }
```

---

**POST request with Multipart FormData/Multipart Form File**:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(postRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com"));
}

IEnumerator postRequest(string url)
{
    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("field1=foo&field2=bar"));
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("my file data", "myfile.txt"));

    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

---

**PUT request**:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(putRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com"));
}

IEnumerator putRequest(string url)
{
    byte[] dataToPut = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, This is a test");
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Put(url, dataToPut);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

---

**DELETE request**:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(deleteRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com"));
}

IEnumerator deleteRequest(string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Delete(url);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Deleted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Code after "yield return" runs on the main thead, isn't it?

Comment: I've tried your code, but nothing happens, when I call your method... What am I doing wrong? Here is [my base request class](https://pastebin.com/zSpuXMRD), then [implementation](https://pastebin.com/vmYPbFYT) and call: `new AuthorizationRequest("test124", "Test1234").execute();`. Program doesn't enter in execute method...

Comment: Like I said, `UnityWebRequest` is implemented to run in another Thread. coroutine is used to wait/yield for it to finish the request. The yield is imply waiting for  `UnityWebRequest` which is **one another Thread** to finish. It does not block the main Thread while yielding. That's why coroutines are awesome.

Comment: My examples shows how to make a http request and also with json. If you copy the json example as it is and paste in your Editor **without** modifying it, it should work. If you modify it and it doesn't work, create a new question. Before you create a new question, I want to tell you the problem I found in your code. `execute` is a coroutine function and should **not** be called directly like you did. It should be called with `StartCoroutine(execute())` function. Take a look at my example again. You must add the `yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();` otherwise you  will have issues in the future.

Comment: Finally, the class with the coroutine(`execute`) function **must** inherit from `MonoBehaviour` before you can use `StartCoroutine` function to start the coroutine function. Your class does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. If you don't want to inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509118/3785314) as I described how to do this **without** inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`. Please fix all these before replying to this comment. If you run into a problem, ask a new question but post your code in that question.

Comment: @Programmer what if you use `https` with your own cerificate? Unity documentation has literally no information on it =/

Comment: @Sir Not with `UnityWebRequest` but you should be able to do that with standard C# API like [HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient).

Comment: @Programmer any chance you can include that in the answer, i think https i kinda mandatory these days for a lot of games with login/register stuff. I think a lot of unity dev's don't even realise it and just release non secure stuff.

Comment: @Sir it's not mandatory unless you are making a bank/billing software. As for just login/register stuff, you can just use OAuth 2 + encryption. Although I've seen many ignored Unity questions about SSL so I will update this answer but you need to show what you have tried first from the link I provided above then the problems you ran into. I will take it from there. You can use pastebin or whatever site you want to host the code you tried then link it here.

Comment: The only thing i did not understand is how to get it to accept my certificate from the client. I have https code done but the server rejects the request. But i don't know how i validate my certificate in code theres no examples.

Comment: @Programmer just want to ask if this is comptible in `Android/IOS`?

Comment: @Bluetree Yes, it should work on any platform Unity supports.

Comment: @Programmer Can I use **POST request with Multipart FormData/Multipart Form File:**  to send image saved in `Application.persistentDataPath` and send it to php server?

Comment: @Bluetree It's right there in my answer. See the `MultipartFormFileSection` under that second. See many of its constructor  overload [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html).

Comment: It seems they changed constructor, can you update your answer? Seems like the method is now in parameters. and instead of formData have to use some uploadHandler

Answer (score 2):

Use HttpClient and something like:

```
public static HttpContent DoPost(object payload, string subPath)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Global.BaseUrl);
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); // if you're using json service

        // make request
        var response = Global.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(subPath.TrimLeadingSlash(), payload).Result;

        // check for error
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // return result
        return response.Content;
    }
```

Payload is an object to be serialized to json. If all requests are going to the same baseUrl, you can set up HttpClient globally, and reuse it here

Comment: Looks clear. I'll try it. But what about doing it asynchronous?

Comment: .Result on the end of the request is what makes it synchronous. If you remove that, you can use task / await, etc

Comment: there is no HttpClient class found... And package System.Net.Http doesn't exist.

Comment: yes... you can't use HttClient class from Unity in this moment with the current version of the .NET Framework (3.5)

Comment: Unity supports 4.5 if you change the settings in the engine. for unity versions 2017.x and up.

Comment: What is Payload??

Comment: Most of the time, if you're doing a POST, you're sending some sort of object over the wire to an endpoint. The payload is the object that you're sending. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118249/whats-the-difference-between-request-payload-vs-form-data-as-seen-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

https://www.patrykgalach.com/2019/04/18/how-to-call-rest-api-in-unity/

Please refer this link cleanest way to play with data

and do not use `www` instead of use `UnityWebRequest`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `WWW` and `UnityWebRequest` classes to initiate API calls. WWW got obsolete now and Unity recommends using `UnityWebRequest` over `WWW`.

```
void Start() {
    string url = "https://retrofit-backend-demo.herokuapp.com/book";
    StartCoroutine(GetBooksUsingWWW(url));
    StartCoroutine(GetBooksUsingUnityWebRequest(url));
}

IEnumerator GetBooksUsingWWW(string url) {
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url)){
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log(www.text);
        JSONNode jsonNode = JSON.Parse(www.text);
        string title = jsonNode[0]["title"].ToString();
        Debug.Log("Title: " + title);
    }
}

IEnumerator GetBooksUsingUnityWebRequest(string url) {
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        JSONNode jsonNode = JSON.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);
        string title = jsonNode[0]["title"].ToString();
        Debug.Log("Title: " + title);
    }
}
```

For demo: https://github.com/codemaker2015/api-interaction-unity3d-demo