# 400 bad request - Unity wwwform binary data with audio file

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, wit-ai

Hi guys this is a quick follow up question from a previous post regarding sending an audio file through to an online api in unity.

I think (although maybe wrong) my problem is the correct syntax on the form.AddBinaryData line.

The example curl code for the api is :

```
 $ curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20170307' \
    -i -L \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: audio/wav" \
    --data-binary "@sample.wav"
```

The C# code I'm using is :

```
 IEnumerator GetJSONText2(){
        string file = "Assets/sample.wav"; 
         FileStream filestream = new FileStream (file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader filereader = new BinaryReader (filestream);
         byte[] BA_AudioFile = filereader.ReadBytes ((Int32)filestream.Length);
         WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
         form.AddField("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
         form.AddField("Content-Type", "audio/wav");
         //form.AddField("Content-Length", BA_AudioFile.Length);
         //form.AddBinaryData ("Sample",BA_AudioFile, "sample.wav");
         //form.AddBinaryData ("@sample",BA_AudioFile, "sample.wav", "audio/x-wav");
        form.AddBinaryData ("Sample",BA_AudioFile);
         filestream.Close ();
         filereader.Close ();

    WWW www = new WWW(url, form);

    yield return www;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) {
        print(www.error);
    }else {
        print("Finished Uploading");
        print (www.text);
        Handle (www.text);
    }

}
```

And I'm getting a 400 bad request response.  I feel so close yet so far.  As you can see I've been trying different combination of the AddBinaryData field but it's resulted in me doubting myself even more now.

Thanks for you time reading this.

Comment: It is similar to the other post although the problem I have is the file attachment rather than field headers.

Comment: Nope, you're adding incorrectly the headers, you're adding those as form fields, not headers, you must use the way the post I've linked as duplicate explains to add the headers.

Comment: Ok thanks @Gusman, I'll look into that now, appreciated

Comment: @Diego The question he linked shows how to properly add a header to `WWW`. Please read that. You have to use `Dictionary`

Comment: Will do appreciated