# Send json from Unity to SpringBoot Rest -

Tags: java, spring-boot, unity-game-engine

I am trying to a call a rest end point I made for my unity game, but any time I send the users json details via unity to my Springboot application through a Rest call i get the error ...

> 2018-03-17 02:20:40 [thread] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver -Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON document: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@69ce261; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@69ce261; line: 1, column: 2]

This it my Unity code

```
public IEnumerator CallLogin(string Username, string Password) {


    UnityWebRequest www = 
  UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost:8080/unity/login", new 
     User(Username, Password).ToJson()); 

    www.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/json";

    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.error != null)
    {

        Debug.Log("Error " + www.error);

    }
    else {

        Debug.Log("Response  " + www.downloadHandler.text);

    }

}
```

And this is my Springboot java code

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserModel> Login(@RequestBody User user){

    // check if the username and password provided matches a user in the database.
    String verifiedResponse = this.defaultUserDAOService.verification(user);

    UserModel userModel = new UserModel();

    if(verifiedResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Verified")){ // if the user was verified successfully (Found in the database)

        userModel.setUser(defaultUserDAOService.getByUsername(user.getUserName()))
                .setSuccessful(true)
                .setResponseMessage("Successful");


        return new ResponseEntity<>(userModel, HttpStatus.OK); // return response to client.


    }else{

        userModel.setUser(new User())
                .setSuccessful(false)
                .setResponseMessage("Username or Password is incorrect");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(userModel, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND); // return response to client.

    }


}
```

Finally the User class which has the ToJson function

[Serializable]
public class User : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public User(string userName, string password)
{
    this.userName = userName;

    this.password = password;
}

public string userName;

public string password;


public string ToJson()
{
    return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
}
```

}

I need help please, i have been battling this for hours.

Comment: See this part of your code `User(Username, Password).ToJson()`. Where is the `ToJson()` function?

Comment: @Programmer it in the User class, i updated my post, the last code at the bottom of my question is the user class code, you will see the ToJson() method there, thanks.

Comment: Encode the json with `UTF8Encoding` before sending. See the json section from my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity/46008025#46008025) post. Let me know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @Programmer Alrighty, I am on it.

Comment: @Programmer woow, it actually worked. Thanks alot. I would love to ask you about the UTF8Encoding, but I will go and read it and not bug you. Thanks alot.

Comment: It's used to escape json so that some of its values are not considered as syntax when sending. You are welcome!

Comment: @Programmer lol...thanks you very much sir, I appreciate.

Comment: @Programmer please sir are you on skype ?

Comment: I don't skype but you can always create new question here. You don't have to call people sir on this site,