# namespace error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Data' does not exist in the namespace `System'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5 and the namespace `system.data` in my script.

I added this reference to the project in Visual Studio 2017, but it still giving me the following error from the unity console:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. Are you missing 'System.Data' assembly reference?

What do I need to do?

Comment: What are you expecting to use in the `System.Data` namespace?

Comment: 'System.Data.SqlClient'  i am using SqlConnection, SqlCommand  and  SqlDataReader

Comment: I have a hard time believing you added the reference to your project in Visual Studio, as Unity only allows DLL references to be added via the project. Do you perhaps mean that?

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that `SqlClient` really isn't supported in Unity. It's very unusual to connect *directly* to a SQL Server instance from a mobile client, isn't it?

Comment: I started to use Unity just about a month ago, until now I used only sql in my studies in developing websites .so thats what i am know.I never did it in Unity, you can explain to me how to add the DLL references and where to add

Comment: The proper way to do this is to write the code that commucates with database with php or any other web languages then from Unity use [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) or [`UnityWebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity/46008025#46008025) API to communicate with this API.