# HttpWebRequest not working with WebGL

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have a script that perfectly generates objects from local xml file, now I want to port it in WebGL, but when I am trying to upload xml from server local host doesn't response.
The script that I use for reading xml file from URL:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(receiveStream);
receiveStream.Close();
```

Is there any way to load xml file in Unity for reading data and dynamic objects generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpWebRequest is from the `System.Net` namespace and you can't use any API from the `System.Net` namespace with WebGL platform. You have to use the [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) or [`UnityWebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity/46008025#46008025) API to download the data instead of `HttpWebRequest`. Once you download the data with `HttpWebRequest`, use `XDocument.Parse` to convert the received data into `XDocument` object.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(getRequest("http:///www.yoururl.com"));
}

IEnumerator getRequest(string uri)
{
    //Make request
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);

        //Convert to xml
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

This is for Get request. If post request, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity/46008025#46008025) post.

Comment: Thanks, it very helped me!
It reads xml very well but i can't load it to XDocument, because of error:
"Text node cannot appear in this state. Line 1, position 1"

Comment: Sorry there is a typo in my answer. That should be `XDocument.Parse` as I mention. I said this in the beginning of my answer but messed up in the code. Also, that should be inside the else statement to make sure you don't load xml when there is a download error. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, for sure I've used "Parse" instead "Load", seems it was my XML problem, because of BOM.

Comment: Ok. Got it fixed now?

Comment: Yep, works like a charm with loading options: 
`XDocument xdoc = 
XDocument.Parse(uwr.downloadHandler.text, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);`