# UnityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text is empty, eventhough the POST method returns a response

Tags: unity-game-engine

- I am making a POST api call to my server using UnityWebRequest (Unity version that i have is 2017.4.0f1)
- I am sending some data elements in the request body to the server, which
  inserts into my DB and returns a response body, which is a json string
- I am using
  UnityWebRequest.downloadhandler.text to read the response message,
  but it is empty, eventhough the data elements
  are getting inserted into my DB. request.downloadHandler.data.Length also gives me 0
- Making the same call through
  Postman returns me the appropriate response (so does using
  HTTPWebRequest and reading the response via a stream reader)

This is the code snippet that i have for it:

```
UnityWebRequest request=new UnityWebRequest(endpoint,"POST");
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
request.SetRequestHeader("host",host);
request.SetRequestHeader("X-Amz-Date",dateTime);
request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization",authorizationHeader);

request.uploadHandler=(UploadHandler)new 
UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestParameter));

request.chunkedTransfer=false;
request.downloadHandler=new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
request.SendWebRequest();
print(request.downloadHandler.text);
```

Please advise as to what i am doing wrong here.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the results to be downloaded before you can do anything with it. Webrequests are asynchronous!

Typically, you would use a Coroutine to do this, like

```
public IEnumerator LoadData()
{
    // ......
    // all your code goes here, up to the SendWebRequest line

    // then you yield to wait for the request to return
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    // after this, you will have a result
    print(request.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

Start this coroutine like this:

```
StartCoroutine(LoadData());
```

More examples in the answer to this question: [Sending http requests in C# with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46003824/224734)

Answer (score 0):

As frankhermes says you need wait for the results to be downloaded before you do anything

`yield return request.SendWebRequest();`

But the above line alone didn't work for me.

```
public IEnumerator LoadData()
{
    // ......
    // all your code goes here, up to the SendWebRequest line

    var asyncOperation = request.SendWebRequest();

    while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
    {
     // wherever you want to show the progress:

        float progress = request.downloadProgress;
        Debug.Log("Loading " + progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    while (!request.isDone)
       yield return null; // this worked for me

    // after this, you will have a result
    print(request.downloadHandler.text);
}
```