# Using UnityWebRequest to get response body in a static class

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming

Our WebGL game made using Unity requires getting data from the body of a GET response. Currently this is implemented using a static class, with a blocking while loop to wait for the request to be done:

```cs
public static class NetworkController {
    public MyDataClass GetData() {
        UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(...);
        webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        while (!webRequest.isDone) {} // block here
        // Get body of response webRequest.downloadHandler.text and
        // return a MyDataClass object
    }
}
```

This works in the editor until later we discovered using WebGL [disallows blocking the web request](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html). Unity suggests using coroutines to mitigate that, but `StartCoroutine()` only exists in the `MonoBehaviour` class which our static class cannot inherit from.

Is there a way to continue the execution only after the web request gets a response while using a static class?

---

As per comments, the code is modified so now the static class makes a call to a `MonoBehaviour` singleton:

```cs
public static class NetworkController {
    public MyDataClass GetData() {
        return NetworkControllerHelper.GetInstance().GetData();
    }
}

public class NetworkControllerHelper : MonoBehaviour {
    /* ... GetInstance() method for creating a GameObject and create & return an instance... */

    private MyDataClass coroutineResult = null;

    public MyDataClass GetData() {
        UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(...);
        StartCoroutine(WebRequestCoroutine(webRequest));
        // How do I detect that the coroutine has ended then continue without hanging the program?
        while (coroutineResult == null) {}
        return coroutineResult;
    }

    // Coroutine for trying to get a MyDataClass object
    private IEnumerator WebRequestCoroutine(UnityWebRequest webRequest) {
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        while (!webRequest.isDone) yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        // Creating the MyDataClassObject
        coroutineResult = ...;
        yield break;
    } 
}
```

We need to wait for the resulting MyDataClass to be created, so we check if `coroutineResult` is `null`, but using a while loop to block hangs the program. How do I wait for a some seconds before checking for the loop condition?

Comment: We have one MonoBehavior singleton in our project and we use it to run all coroutines. It's a better design to use WebRequest asynchronously like it's meant to be though.

Comment: How do you hold the MonoBehaviour singleton? When I try to create the instance, Unity complains about MonoBehaviour needing to be attached to a GameObject.

Comment: We have an object in the scene it is attached to.

Comment: To use untiy you sort of have to have at least one GameObject, good thing is ANY monobehaviour attatched to it can run a coroutine, while its body can live in a static class

Comment: Check this Url , you will find what you want : <br> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224602/a-method-for-making-http-requests-on-unity-ios/12606963#12606963

Answer (score 2):

You can't load a resource synchronously in WebGL as explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html?_ga=2.239518915.190060092.1571138773-566927728.1567595363).

Do not block on WWW or WebRequest downloads

Do not use code which blocks on a WWW or WebRequest download, like this:

```
while(!www.isDone) {}
```

Although, I cannot find a proper solution, I need  'webRequest.downloadHandler.text' and I want to use this string globally on another classes.