# Understanding WebRequests

Tags: c#, .net, performance, webrequest

In my code (C#) I'm using a WebRequest:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
```

For some reason this line takes about 2-3 seconds to run. I've looked for a solution, but couldn't find any for the creation of the request. I've tried different urls (http and https, google, etc.) but nothing seems to help. Did anyone else experience such a behavior? Can anyone explain what exactly is going on during the creation of the request? Any alternatives?

BTW - I'm on a 64bit Win 7 (Bootcamp)

Edit - measured 3.126 seconds with Stopwatch for the following code (wireless):

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
```

On the same network, only wired, it took 0.01 seconds.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: How are you measuring the amount of time it takes to create the request?

Comment: How long does it take if you just type the url into a browser?

Comment: If all other sources fail, and you want to see what .Net is doing behind the scenes, you can get a copy of the .Net source itself at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx.

Comment: Justin - I'm measuring with logging - I know it's not very accurate, but it gives an idea.

Beaner - www.google.com for example takes less than a second.

So while creating a request I'm actually accessing it?

Comment: This makes very little sense, it just creates an HttpWebRequest or FtpWebRequest instance, depending on the url.  Takes 3 microseconds on my machine.  You'll need to use a Stopwatch to measure this.

Comment: measured with Stopwatch: 3.126 seconds

Comment: Perhaps your internet connection is very poor?  As Beaner asked, how long does it take you to go to other pages on the internet in your browser?

Comment: As I said - http://www.google.com takes less than a second with chrome and explorer, but WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com") takes 3.126 seconds.

Comment: That's very weird - on the same network, in wireless connection it took 3.126 seconds, and with wired connection - as expected 0.01 seconds.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: When you create a `WebRequest`, it initializes the default proxy. I've had issues in the past where misconfigured proxy settings can cause a significant delay in creating `WebRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603413/120955) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/935728/120955) have found that proxy detection can take a ridiculously long time. If you know there won't be a proxy, try setting the WebRequest's proxy property to null.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.Proxy = null;
```

### Update

I don't have any other ideas, but here are some things you might try to narrow down the problem.

1. Enable logging by putting the following code in your config file:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <system.diagnostics>
       <trace autoflush="true" />
       <switches>
         <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
       </switches>
     </system.diagnostics>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Check out the source code for `WebRequest.Create` in ILSpy or a similar tool, and try doing the same things it does directly. For example, you can try creating a `new HttpWebRequest(...)` rather than calling `WebRequest.Create` and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: This has definitely been a problem for me in the past, with misconfigured proxy settings.

Comment: indeed it's true, but  my delay was for the first line (creation), not for the response. thanks anyways

Comment: @Barracuda: Ah, I was assuming it was the actual connection that was taking so long. I added a couple of additional thoughts. Good luck with this.

Comment: @Barracuda: You may also want to check whether this issue is related: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/c0d5eb13-657d-489d-b9e4-d279d6463e8b/. It sounds like there can be some kind of deadlock when the system tries to open the config file to figure out the connection settings.