# DownloadFileAsync is blocking my App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, downloadfileasync

I am trying to download a large file(around 1GB) my server.When I start downloading I am unable to use the app till the download completes. It is blocking the UI and its becoming unresponsive.

In below code I am calling `DownloadFile` method when the user download button on the UI.And then download starts, but the UI is freezed.

I read that `DownloadFileAsync` won't block the UI. But here its blocking. How to use it in correct way. There are several answers but none is working when I am testing.

**Code:**

Button call:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Debug.WriteLine("1");           
        DownloadGamefile DGF = new DownloadGamefile();
        Debug.WriteLine("2" + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        DGF.DownloadFile("URL(https link to zip file)", Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\ABC.zip");
        Debug.WriteLine("3");
 }
```

Download code:

```
 class DownloadGamefile
{
    private volatile bool _completed;

    public void DownloadFile(string address, string location)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
        _completed = false;

        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgress);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(Uri, location);

    }

    private void DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
            (string)e.UserState,
            e.BytesReceived,
            e.TotalBytesToReceive,
            e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
        }

        _completed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know `DownloadFileAsync` is causing your UI to freeze? What are you using `DownloadCompleted` for? I bet it's something to do with that.

Comment: As of now I just wrote it, But not using it any where.Edited Code.

Comment: The only way that `DownloadFileAsync` could be blocking the UI thread is if it doesn't return until the file has finished downloading. Is that what's happening? If you place a breakpoint on that call and then step, does the debugger step to the next line straight away or does it sit on the method call until the file has downloaded?

Comment: I know because I am unable to use the app after clicking the Download btn, untill the download completes

Comment: This code does neither block, nor does it use WPF. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @djkp: Show us how you use `DownloadFile` from you Download button Click handler. You must be doing something else in there.

Comment: You need to await the downloadfileasync call

Comment: @loneshark99 That won't explain the behaviour he is seeing. Not awaiting an async method will not block the call.

Comment: I updated with button click function code

Comment: @IlianPinzon ofcourse not. take a look at this thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866059/webclient-downloadfileasync-blocks-thread

Comment: How often is the progress reported... is the progress constantly getting reported?

Comment: @loneshark99: according to your link, awaiting the call (as you suggested) won't help at all. the problem is within the progress handler.

Comment: @IlianPinzon i know, I was pointing that link to the guy/girl who posted the question. For you the only comment was ofcourse not.

Comment: Yeah constantly

Comment: @djkp if you comment that line the progress line.. does it still block ur UI

Comment: @djkp you can add the downloaded bytes as a variable and only report when it downloads a certain percentage by adding the downloaded value. That should solve ur issue.

Comment: Yeah currently I am reporting for every 2 seconds , its working :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866059/webclient-downloadfileasync-blocks-thread). The actual problem is getting lots of feedback about the number of bytes downloaded(about progress of download process). Take a timer to get progress for every 2 seconds or any time, this solved the problem.